# How to mark expected failures in SUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, smalltalk, pharo

How can I mark a unit test in SUnit (or phexample) as expected failures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overwrite expectedFailures in your test. There's an example in WeakSetTest:

```
expectedFailures
    "such tests work in Squeak"
    ^ #(testDoAfter testIncludes )
```

**Update:**

[As of Pharo 1.2](http://code.google.com/p/pharo/issues/detail?id=3143), you can also add a  pragma to the test method:

```
testDontWork
    <expectedFailure>
    self assert: 3 equals: 4
```